# drawing UIImage inside a CGMutablePath

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Given a CGMutablePathRef how do I draw a UIImage in it? I know that you can draw it like the following:

```
 UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        [scaledImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

but I am not sure if I have a path (which is a rectangle with rounded corner) how do I add an image in it?

Comment: Apple doc says: "You should call this function only when a bitmap-based graphics context is the current graphics context. If the current context is nil or was not created by a call to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, this function returns nil." , is that your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "draw within a CGMutablePath" I have to assume you mean "**clip to** a CGMutablePath." In that case, you just need to add the path to the current context (`CGContextAddPath()` or any of the path-building functions like `CGContextAddLineToPoint()`) and then call `CGContextClip()`. You can then draw your image in the context with something like `drawAtPoint:` or `CGContextDrawImage()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are choosing the hard way of doing it.

Your approach assumes that you have already got a bitmap and created a bitmap based graphics context. At your place I would just use UIImage's :

```
- (void)drawAtPoint:(CGPoint)point;
```